# change dynamic text value in different frame Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have problem with dynamic text update value.

When I set the value in frame 1, it works fine, but problem came when I go to frame 2, the value didnt change.

here's the code

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class test extends MovieClip {


        public function test() {
            // constructor code
            if (this.currentFrame == 1){
                changeTitle("frame 1");
            }
            else if (this.currentFrame == 2){
                changeTitle("frame 2");
            }
        }
        public function changeTitle(newTitle:String){
            label_title.text = newTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you call `test()`? The function should work fine if called at the right time...

Answer (score -1):

Inside the constructor code the currentFrame for that DisplayObject will always be the first.

Maybe what you want to check is the currentFrame of the container of the object but you can't know that from the constructor as well, you need to wait until it's been added to a display list.

Comment: I didn't get it, so, how should I apply into the code?

Comment: I think you should familiarize yourself with the display list first, there's a comprehensive guide here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e58.html that includes explanations of how to traverse and manipulate it

Comment: it will take time a lot, but I will learn it, thanks for the answer by the way